# Create an array in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm searching really much, but maybe I can't understand the results.

I found only that a array in SWIFT have as index int-values

```
var myArray = [String]()

myArray.append("bla")
myArray.append("blub")

println(myArray[0]) // -> print the result   bla
```

But I will add a String with an String as index-key

```
var myArray = [String:String]()

myArray.append("Comment1":"bla")
myArray.append("Comment2":"blub")

println(myArray["Comment1"]) // -> should print the result bla
```

How should i declare the array and how I can append a value then to this array?

Comment: Did you read the chapter "Collection Types" in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) ?

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is dictionary

```
myArray["key"] = "value"
```

If you want array of dictionaries you would have to declare it like this

```
var myArray: [[String: String]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is an array. Your second example is a dictionary.

For a dictionary you use key value pairing...

```
myArray["Comment1"] = "Blah"
```

You use the same to fetch values...

```
let value = myArray["Comment1"]
println(value)
```

Comment: Aha, thats the difference. Thank you for this information

Comment: No worries. Of course, I'd maybe call it something else. Using the name "Array" for a dictionary could be confusing :-)

Answer (score 0):

You got the concept of array in the first example but for the second one you need a dictionary as they operate on key value pair

```
// the first String denotes the key while the other denotes the value
var myDictionary :[String:String] = ["username":"NSDumb"]
let value = myDictionary["username"]!;
println(value)
```

Quick reference for dictionaries collection type can be [found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Dictionary.html)